# Performance Impact of Session Variables PHP

Tags: php, session

I have user information which I wants to retain in session. I am using memcache as session save handler. I have two approach for storing user info

```
$_SESSION['uname'] = 'abx';
$_SESSION['email'] = 'abx@am.com';
$_SESSION['profilepage'] = 'http://t';
$_SESSION['role'] = '1';
$_SESSION['profilepicture'] = 'http://t';
$_SESSION['gender'] = 'M';
```

OR

```
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->uname = 'abx';
$obj->email = 'abx@am.com';
$obj->profilepage = 'http://t';
$obj->role = 1;
$obj->profilepicture = 'http://t';
$obj->gender = 'M';
$_SESSION['user'] = $obj;
```

I wants to know which one approach is better. Do having multiple session variables has any performance impact.

Comment: How much data are we talking about? How often do you read/write in the session?

Comment: More over user information data will be there. Where ever I need user data will use session.

Comment: You have asked 40 questions up till now, but never accepted an answer. Please work on your acceptance-rate (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). This might be one of the reasons people don't like to answer your questions with much enthusiasm.

Comment: @st2erw2od sure I will work on acceptance going forward. Actually was not about it and nothing was otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The performance impact with just this little data amount you mentioned in the question and comments is very little to non-existent. Internally you will be able to measure some very small differences with a benchmark test, but this won't speed things up more.

In this scenario I would try and consider the benefits of clean, reusable and maintainable code over performance. The second object-oriented approached makes a lot more sense in my opinion and is considered best-practice.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to st2erw2od's answer (I absolutely agree with him), I only want to add that to me this does not sound like a good use-case for a session.

The session should not contain all of the user's data and / or complete objects with userdata. It should only contain the necessary data, e.g. which user is authenticated. Every other stuff like his e-mail address, profile picture, etc. should then be loaded from the database (file system, etc.) according to specific rules (e.g. when they're needed or a complete user entity, etc.). So in this case I recommend just saving the user ID in the session and then load the information from the database.

The main advantage of this is: a) Clearer (and less code); b) Your information is always up-to-date and synced with the database, otherwise you could have some severe bugs.

Comment: I agree, thank you for adding this information to help the OP.

Comment: @Andreas Agree limited information should be stored in session but minimal required information should have been in session or cache layer. Otherwise on every page you will make additional hit on DB

Comment: @user524694: You have to hit the database anyway to load additional information. Nowadays you usually work with some kind of models like entities anyway that needs to be loaded.